# SharePoint form-based authentication with custom database

Tags: sharepoint, authentication

I have SharePoint site and I want to use form-based authentication, not Windows how it is by default.

For this I read that I have to modify the web.config from Central Administration and web.config from my site with the membership and roleManager tags configured properly.

But if I use this:

`<membership>
<providers>
 <add name="MyProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, 
             System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,

             PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
             .../>
 </providers>
</membership>`

System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider requires a database generated with ASP.NET SQL Server Setup Wizard (aspnet_regsql.exe), and this is my problem!
I want to use another database with cunstom table 'Users' from where to take the username and password for authentication.
How can I do this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you have a custom database structure, then you will need to write a custom [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx). I suggest starting [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) on MSDN.